# For real numbers $x,y$ and $z$ if $9x^2+16y^2+4z^2=108$ and $6xy+4yz+3zx=54$. Find value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, online-resources, calculator, ellipsoids

**Question**

> For real numbers $x,y$ and $z$ if $9x^2+16y^2+4z^2=108$ and $6xy+4yz+3zx=54$. Find value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

**My calculations**

I found
$$(3x+4y+2z)^2=108+4×54=324$$
I have no clue how to proceed further .

But for check of validity of question I let wolfram solve it . But results left me more puzzled .
[image]

Now how can I get to this result .
There is one more picture

[image]

Now why I don't get same result $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Feel free to edit , comment and advise . Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=3x,b=4y,c=2z$. Then we have $a^2+b^2+c^2=108$ and $\frac{ab+bc+ac}2=54$ i.e. $$a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ac=108,$$ which implies $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac=\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}2=0$$ and thus $a=b=c$ and since $a^2+b^2+c^2=108$, we have $a^2=b^2=c^2=\frac{108}3=36$ so that $$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2\cdot\left(\frac19+\frac1{16}+\frac14\right)=\frac{61}4.$$

Comment: Thanks , can u check first image please

Comment: @Rishi Can you maybe post a link to Wolfram Alpha how you got that output

Comment: Compute 'find x^2+y^2+z^2 , 9x^2+16y^2+4z^2=a , 6xy+4yz+3zx=b' with the Wolfram|Alpha website (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2+%2C+9x%5E2%2B16y%5E2%2B4z%5E2%3Da+%2C+6xy%2B4yz%2B3zx%3Db) or mobile app (wolframalpha:///?i=find+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2+%2C+9x%5E2%2B16y%5E2%2B4z%5E2%3Da+%2C+6xy%2B4yz%2B3zx%3Db).

Comment: @Rishi Indeed this seems to be a mistake in the Wolfram Software (it is clear that the result can't be correct for all $x,y,z,a,b$)

Answer (score 1):

$$0=9x^2+16y^2+4z^2-2(6xy+4yz+3zx)=\frac{1}{2}((3x-4y)^2+(3x-2z)^2+(4y-2z)^2),$$
which gives $$3x=4y=2z.$$
Now, let $3x=t.$

Thus, $$t^2+t^2+t^2=108$$ or $$t^2=36,$$ which gives
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{t^2}{9}+\frac{t^2}{16}+\frac{t^2}{4}=4+\frac{9}{4}+9=\frac{61}{4}.$$

Comment: Sir i got it , Thanx . Now please check first image i uploaded , what went wrong .